# Java copying using built in LinkedList

Tags: java, list, linked-list, copy, live

I have a question about copying a `LinkedList`. I'm working on a project that is taking in data and storing it in a `LinkedList`. This is done through a live feed via a network port and I want to be able to copy the data from this list to another one so as to process the data collected. Since there is always data being collected is there a way like in C to change the "pointers" so that the head of the first list is now associated with the second `LinkedList` were as the first would then be empty for new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you need is 2 Queues. There's 1 queue for collecting and 1 for processing. At some point, you need to swap them back and forth. As long as you lock briefly for the switch, everything should be ok. There's no need to mess around with the pointers on the linked list, AND you can avoid copying contents around.

That being said, maybe you should consider looking at the concurrency packages for Executors that work off of Queues. Without knowing much about your specific task, it seems like those might be a better match for what you are doing and allow you to avoid having to code the details by hand.

EDIT: This is the package I'm talking about. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: I was thinking about that, and so far this might be the best answer to the problem. I'll looking into the package you linked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
second.addAll(first);
first.clear();
```

Comment: Do you know the time complexity of the addAll()? Since I am taking in data I was afraid that addAll() would take x time which y number of data had been added to the first linked list during x time and using clear() would resulting in the loss of the y number of data.

Comment: Looks like addAll calls toArray on the collection to be added, then iterates through the array adding the elements one by one.

Comment: The complexity would unfortunately be `O(n)` simply because there's no way to retrieve the underlying node structure in a `LinkedList`. However if performance is really an issue, I suggest writing your own `LinkedList` implementation that supports concatenation.

Comment: When it calls toArray would this call be a deep copy?

Comment: I would like a deep copy as like I said I am worried about concurrence. Is there a way to extend the Linked List class to add the nessesary methods?

Answer (score 0):

What about one of:

`linkedlist.push(newHeadValue);`
or

`linkedlist.addFirst(newHeadValue);`
or

`linkedlist.add(0,newHeadValue);`

or do you explicitly want a step where the head has no data?

Comment: I don't need a step where the head is null. I just need to copy the data to another linked list. I mostly worried about concurrence.

Comment: Appoligies. I didn't understand the question in that you wanted to end up with 2 lists sharing tails.